# jQuery .load() is not working on https:// connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, https, cloudflare

Recently I've added an SSL certificate using Cloudflare to my website, and since then the function below started to return a `0 (error)` and never loads the content of the URL, what should I do to fix that.

```js
$(function () {
  EnderReact();
});

function EnderReact () {
  $("a").on("click", function () {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!(($(this).attr('href')).replace(/\s/g, '') > 0)) {
      var TheURL = $(this).attr('href');
    }

    if (TheURL && !(TheURL.indexOf("http") > -1 || TheURL.indexOf("https") > -1 || TheURL.indexOf("//") > -1)) {
      TheURL = "https://" + TheURL + "?v=0.001";
      $("#MyDiv").load(TheURL, { name: '' },
        function (response, status, xhr) {
          EnderReact();
          if (status == "error")
            alert(xhr.status + " (" + xhr.statusText + ")");
          else
            alert(xhr.status + " (" + xhr.statusText + ")");
        });
    }
  });
}
```

NOTE: the console error is `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED means that the domain you are using in the url is invalid or doesn't have an `A` or `AAAA` record. Probably the code that you are using for resolve the url is broken. Try console.log the result of url transformation.

Answer (score 0):

That is a general issue for cloudflare ssl settings.
 check their gaq :

[here](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/add-html-app-jquery/108284)

try this code and see which line has error :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("http:") > -1){ 
       console.log("URL contains http");
    }else if(window.location.href.indexOf("https:") > -1){ 
       console.log("URL contains https");
    }else if(window.location.href.indexOf("//") > -1) {
       console.log("URL contains twitter");
    }
});
```

Comment: No, What I get in the console is:
`POST https://TheURL net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: Did you change your nameserver to given nameservers from cloudflare ?

Comment: yeah, I have changed it

Comment: see my updated answer use that code to see if it works edit to your url parameters first `TheURL`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```